# TFS Queue Build based on Label

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is it possible to queue a build based on

1. a label
2. a specific branch?

Comment: please explain what you mean with "specific branch"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specifying the label in the "GetVersion" field with a **L** at the beginning.
This is possible if queue queue a normal build and also for a private build.

Look [here](http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/tfs-build-build-by-label.html) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately I get error below:
metaproj: The specified solution configuration "UATBranch|Any CPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a build by label. However, you must also create a Project and add your files to the solution.  (Note I did this on Visual Studio 2013)

Step by step:

1) Create a SLN Project and add files you want to include
2) Modify the csproj file to include everything:  (Replace OUT*, you will need to do for each folder level with the path to the files to deploy defined in solution, ie OUT*** as many levels as necessary)

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="OUT\*">
<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="OUT\*\*">
<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    </ItemGroup>
```

3) Check in the Project source control
4) Create Label - add the following items : Files you want to deploy, SLN , CSPROJ, AssemblInfo.cs and save **Important, the CSPROJ should always be the same file and use wildcard in the folders. 
5) Create Build Definition - Use Default Template. Set "Get Version" property to your LABEL with L in front. 
  For example:  LMOOLABEL (label is MOOLABEL) 
6) Kick off and a build and make sure it completes and copies files over to drop location

Configurations I use:

```
ReleaseDefaulTemplate.11.1.xaml
MSBuild Arguements: /p:GetVersion=Lversion;VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```